# Django guardian several permissions with get_objects_for_user

Tags: django, django-guardian

If I pass in one permission at a time get_objects_for_user works fine

```
>>> projects = get_objects_for_user(alvin, 'view_project', klass=Project)
>>> projects
<QuerySet [<Project: Central whole.>]>
>>> projects = get_objects_for_user(alvin, 'change_project', klass=Project)
>>> projects
<QuerySet [<Project: Education soldier.>, <Project: Evening cold.>]>
```

Now from the [docs](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/check.html?highlight=get_objects_for_user#get-objects-for-user)

> It is also possible to provide list of permissions rather than single
> string,

But this does fail to return anything

```
>>> projects = get_objects_for_user(alvin, ('change_project', 'view_project'), klass=Project)
>>> projects
<QuerySet []>
```

what am I doing wrong when passing the permissions list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gues you need to add `any_perm=True`

```py
projects = get_objects_for_user(
    alvin, 
    ('change_project', 'view_project'), 
    klass=Project, 
    any_perm=True,
)
```

[Docs](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/guardian.shortcuts.html#get-objects-for-user)

> • any_perm – if True, any of permission in sequence is accepted. Default is False.